# My AJax Request Not Woking On click of an icon

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel-8

i want to send a ajax call on click of a icon.

Admin.js

```
$('.user-status').click(function() {
    var userId = this.id;
    var userStatus = $(this).attr('data-status');
    alert('clicked');

    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: siteUrl + 'admin/change-user-status',
        data: { userId: userId, userStatus: userStatus },
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    })

})
```

Route.php

`Route::get('/admin/change-user-status', [AdminController::class, 'changeUserStatus']);`

But when I click on icon I am getting the alert clicked, but the ajax call is not being initiated.

The alert is coming

[image]

But no ajax request initiated

[image]

No error in console

[image]

i am using webpack

```
mix.js(['resources/js/dashboard-template.js', 'resources/js/admin.js'], 'public/js/admin.js');
```

Comment: When you use alert, this is blocking code and the code after WILL NOT execute until you close the alert. Are you doing this?

Comment: Try to avoid debugging using `alert` and similar functions, they'll drive you crazy, especially if you accidentally use them in a loop

Comment: Building on what Chris has said, either use a debugger (chrome and firefox have these built in if needed) or logs via the console.

Comment: try adding token to ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tool: "Network" (see screenshot)
And you will be able to see if it is well sent.
An ajax request is by default sent with "xhr", so I advise you to sort by xhr as I did on the screenshot

[Network screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlE8C.png)

You should also add the error method and a timeout (to be sure that the server returns a response)

```js
$('.user-status').click(function() {
        var userId = this.id;
        var userStatus = $(this).attr('data-status');
        alert('clicked');

        $.ajax({
            type: "get",
            url: siteUrl + 'admin/change-user-status',
            data: { userId: userId, userStatus: userStatus },
            dataType: 'html',
            timeout: 5000, //ms
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function(a,b,c){
                console.log(a,b,c)
            }
        })
    })
```

Comment: Thank you.

That helped me solve the problem